# regex: how to replace a group of tags as a whole?

Tags: html, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all meta tags with a set of new meta tags. I have the following code

```
<?php
$header = '
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
<title>meta replace test</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta name="description" content="..." />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>';


$meta = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <meta name="resource-type" content="document" />
    <meta name="distribution" content="global" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="2000, 2002, 2005, 2007 phpBB Group" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9" />';

$regex = '/<meta.*\/>/';
preg_match_all($regex, $header, $matches);
$header = preg_replace($regex, $meta, $header);

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($matches); 
echo "</pre>";
```

the meta tags in the `$header` should be replaced with the meta tags from `$meta`. There are 3 meta tags in the `$header` so it will replace 3 times unless I put all the meta tags next to eachother. I only want to replace once, no matter how many tags there are.

The regex I use is the following:

```
$regex = '/<meta.*\/>/';
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: ah thanks .. myeah that's gonna be problematic. I guess I'll have to update my code but can't right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace all the `<meta...>` tags with the contents of `$meta`, you’ll have to remove the tags as a separate step, and then insert your replacement at a particular point.

This solution *requires* that the tags are in a well-formed format. Note that it hasn’t been tested.

```
$header = preg_replace(/<meta\s.*?\/>/isg, "", $header);
$header = preg_replace(/(<\/title>[\s\n]*)/is, "$1$meta", $header);
```